# Cocapods not generating resources bundle

Tags: git, cocoapods, bundle

I've developed a private framework in Swift and I'm distributing it via Cocoapods in a git repo.

When I install the pod in a Swift project it works fine and the resources bundle is generated. But if I try to import it from an ObjC project the resources bundle is not created. I don't know if it's a problem in my podspec or a problem with Cocoapods.

Podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

s.platform = :ios
s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
s.name = "SMC_iOS"
s.summary = "SMC."
s.requires_arc = true

s.version = "0.0.1"
s.license = { :type => "Copyright", :file => "./SMC/LICENSE" }
s.author = { "..." => "..." }
s.homepage = "..."

s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'SMC/SMC_iOS.framework'
s.source = { :path => './SMC/SMC_iOS.framework' }
s.source_files = "SMC_iOS/**/*.{swift,h,m}"
s.resource_bundles = {'SMC_iOS' => ['SMC_iOS/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib,xcassets,strings}']}

end
```

Derived Data:

Swift build:

[image: SWIFT-BUILD]

Objective C build: (**Missing Bundle**)

[image: OBJC-BUILD]

Comment: add `-ObjC` in Other Linker Flag inside Build Setting

Comment: I didn't know that but I've checked it and it was already set. Thanks anyway!

Comment: did you try to import in Bridging_Header file??

Comment: Yes, and the apps are launching correctly, but the assets, strings and storyboards are not being included in a bundle in Obj-C. Thanks.